# IOS significant-change location services?

Tags: ios, service, location

According to apple's document,there are several ways to track the user’s location in the background.One is the significant-change location service,another is standard location service. That significant-change location service is available only in ios4.0 and later for devices with cellular radios.
Question:
.Which devices are not available for significant-change location services?

Comment: Can you give the link for the document?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3.Tracking the user's location section.